# C# - Change Default Of A Struct?

Tags: c#, constants, default, point

**Asked simple:** Can I change the `default` of a `struct` ?

- If yes, how ?
- if no, is there an elegant way achieving the *behaviour* below ?

---

`Point` or `PointF` return `x = 0` and `y = 0` but I would like to make it return `x = -1` and `y = -1`. **Reason:**

- `x = 0` and `y = 0` is in my application a valid value
- `x = -1` and `y = -1` is in my application an invalid value

I would like to return just an invalid value when I can't compute a valid one. I could define a `const` but that would be a few in all classes that are involved in calculation of Points.

---

**Answer:** No.

**Suggested solutions:**

- `struct` → `class` and init values with `-1`, instead of `default()` use `new TheClass()`

Comment: No, you can't. They are initialised to 0.

Comment: why not convert your struct into a class then have a constructor that assigns negative values in it

Comment: You can't change the default values for structs even if you have access to the source code - they always have a default constructor that initialises all value types to 0 and all references to null.

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo: that would be the simplest way to go, but probably `Point` and `PointF` come from some external library and they cannot be modified...

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo I use `Point` and `PointF` from .NET Framework because they are also drawn and stuff. That I do for clean modularity.

Comment: Either use nullable as suggested below, or follow your own suggestion and use a const (or static readonly) "error" value. Depending on the size of your struct, this could save memory and/or comparison time

Answer (score 1):

Structs cannot override the parameterless default constructor, nor can they explicitly initialize their fields.

What you could do is use nullable points `Point?` and use null for invalid values.